# Siesta - Test Dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, extjs, siesta

I have several test files in Siesta for my ExtJS application. Some of those tests must be ran and pass before others should begin. Is there a way to execute tests only after a previous test has passed?

Answer (score 1):

In [Siesta](http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/) you can use tests to run both asynchronous code and can do chaining and waiting. For more information you can see the [Get Started Guide](http://www.bryntum.com/docs/siesta/#!/guide/siesta_getting_started) but I've included an example here for completeness as well.

Using [wait](http://www.bryntum.com/docs/siesta/#!/api/Siesta.Test-method-wait), one of the async methods:

```
t.wait('xhrSample');

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url     : 'ajax_demo/sample.json',

    success : function (response, opts) {
        t.is(response, 'foobar', 'Response is correct');

        t.endWait('xhrSample');
    },

    failure : function (response, opts) {
        t.fail("request failed");

        t.endWait('xhrSample');
    }
});
```

Using [chain](http://www.bryntum.com/docs/siesta/#!/api/Siesta.Test-method-chain) in Siesta:

```
t.chain(
    function (next) {
        t.type(userNameField, 'username', next)
    },
    function (next) {
        t.type(passwordField, 'secret', next)
    },
    function (next) {
        t.click(loginButton, next)
    },
    function () {
        // done
    }
});
```

And lasting using waitFor:

```
this.waitFor(
    // The condition to check for, this line will mean waiting until the presence of #foo element
    function() { return document.getElementById('foo'); },  

    // The callback, after the condition has been fulfilled
    function(el) { /* DO COOL STUFF */ }          
);
```

If you have other questions, I'd likely need more information strictly about what you are waiting for Siesta to finish.